# how to add basicHttpBinding to the custombinding code

Tags: wcf, web-config

I need to  authenticate an endpoint using certificate in WCF Config file
I have tried adding with the various `authenticationMode` setting
but its not working in `customBinding`
could you please help me to convert the below code to the custom binding

```
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="certBinding">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

This is the code i have tried in custom binding

```
<customBinding>
        <binding name="OutbBinding1" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="20000000" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
            <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation">
            <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="AnonymousForCertificate" />
            </security>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know, if we use the message security of BasicHttpbinding, we should set up the certificate both in the client and the server. In addition, we should also establish a certificate trust relationship between the server and the client.
One more thing needs to note is, different from the authentication mode of the transport layer security, we need to set a default service certificate (non-client certificate, use the trusted server certificates for signing messages) on the client side.
So anyway, the below configuration could achieve the same goal that authenticates the client with a certificate. please refer to the below configuration.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="TehRealBinding">
        <textMessageEncoding />
        <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" />
        <httpTransport />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Besides, the following document might be useful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/securitybindingelement-authentication-modes
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the Response, I have tried with the MutualCertificate, but it is not working . when I call the endpoint HTTPS  url though the browser, it works fine, (web browser page property shows "TLS 1.2, AES with 256 bit encryption (High); ECDH_P256 with 256 bit exchange") what changes should need to be made in the above bindings to make this work, I tried almost all the authentication mode nothing is working, Please help me

Comment: Before you authenticate the client with a certficate by using your costom binding, I recommend that you complete the following official example first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client

Comment: there might be something wrong with the certificate, we could the IIS Service certificate module to create a certificate for the test.

Comment: Please establish a trust relationship first, then provide a service certificate and client certificate when invoking the service.